# Passing output of a CNN to BILSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, conv-neural-network

I am working on a project in which I have to pass the output of CNN to Bi directional LSTM. I created the model as below but it is throwing 'incompatible' error. Please let me know where I am going wrong and how to fix this

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3,input_shape = (32,32,1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=1, padding='valid'))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size=3))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 48, kernel_size=3))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size=3))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(filters = 80, kernel_size=3))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(96)))
    model.add(Dense(total_words/2, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
    model.add(Dense(total_words, activation='softmax'))
    
    model.summary()
```

The error returned is:

```
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-24-261befed7006> in <module>()
         27 model.add(Activation('relu'))
         28 
    ---> 29 model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(150, return_sequences=True)))
         30 model.add(Dropout(0.3))
         31 model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(96)))
    
    5 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
        178                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
        179                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
    --> 180                          str(x.shape.as_list()))
        181     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
        182       ndim = x.shape.ndims
    
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 1, 1, 80]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the data passed to `LSTM` and it can be solved inside your network. The `LSTM` expects 3D data while `Conv2D` produces 4D. There are two possibilities you can adopt:

**1)** make a reshape `(batch_size, H, W*channel)`;

**2)** make a reshape `(batch_size, W, H*channel)`.

In these ways, you have 3D data to use inside your LSTM. below an example

```
def ReshapeLayer(x):
    
    shape = x.shape
    
    # 1 possibility: H,W*channel
    reshape = Reshape((shape[1],shape[2]*shape[3]))(x)
    
    # 2 possibility: W,H*channel
    # transpose = Permute((2,1,3))(x)
    # reshape = Reshape((shape[1],shape[2]*shape[3]))(transpose)
    
    return reshape

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, input_shape = (32,32,3)))
model.add(Lambda(ReshapeLayer))  # <============
model.add(LSTM(16))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',)
model.summary()
```

Comment: FYI: The first possibility you've provided is equal to using `model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))`

Answer (score 0):

`Conv2D` has 2-dimensional input/output but an LSTM takes 1-dimensional input. This is why it is expecting 3 dimensions (Batch, Sequence, Hid) but finding 4 (Batch, X, Y, Hid). The solution is to e.g. use the `Flatten` layer after the CNN and before the LSTM to project the output to a 1-dimensional sequence.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. Adding flatten is making the output 2D. So I am still getting incompatibility issues. error message - "Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 80]" . Any ideas?