# tensorflow / keras: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a basic CRNN model that looks like this:

```
char_list = string.ascii_letters+string.digits 
#Model
inputs = Input(shape=(32,300,1))
 
conv_1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(inputs)
pool_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(conv_1)
conv_2 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(pool_1)
pool_2 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2)(conv_2)
conv_3 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(pool_2)
conv_4 = Conv2D(256, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(conv_3)
pool_4 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(conv_4)
conv_5 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(pool_4)
batch_norm_5 = BatchNormalization()(conv_5)
conv_6 = Conv2D(512, (3,3), activation = 'relu', padding='same')(batch_norm_5)
batch_norm_6 = BatchNormalization()(conv_6)
pool_6 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 1))(batch_norm_6)
conv_7 = Conv2D(512, (2,2), activation = 'relu')(pool_6)

squeezed = Lambda(lambda x: K.squeeze(x, 1))(conv_7)

blstm_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(squeezed)
blstm_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(blstm_1)

outputs = Dense(len(char_list)+1, activation = 'softmax')(blstm_2)

act_model = Model(inputs, outputs)
```

if the input is of shape `(32,300,1)` it works, but if I try to change the height in the input to 64 `(64,300,1)` , I get an error:

> ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 3 for '{{node lambda_2/Squeeze}} = SqueezeT=DT_FLOAT, squeeze_dims=[1]' with input shapes: [?,3,74,512].

why this error occurs? and how to solve it?

Comment: you can consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/63789979/10375049

Comment: After `conv7` layer check the dimension, when you use `K.squeeze(x, 1)` the dimension for the input which you are providing must be `(?, 1, ?, ..)`, the dim must be 1 at index 1. You may refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) link for squeeze doc.

Comment: If you are using softmax activation you should set its loss to `categorical_crossentropy`. And if using the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss, your targets should be integer targets.